# Antlr4 c++ get name of rule from ParseTree *

Tags: c++, antlr4

While traversing the parse tree created, I need a way to get the name of the parser rule from the `antlr4:tree:ParseTree *` node that I am currently traversing

for example if the grammar is:

```
t: AB;
```

(ignore lexer rules for now) and t is some rule, I need to check if the node (type: ParseTree *) corresponds to rule t.

Thanks

Comment: I would think something like this. `auto x = *(RuleContext*)node; auto ri = x.getRuleIndex; auto name = parser.getRuleNames[ri];`

Comment: error: use of deleted function 'antlr4::RuleContext::RuleContext(const antlr4::RuleContext&)'
   16 |     auto x = *(antlr4::RuleContext*)node;
      |                                     ^~~~

Comment: some problem with RuleContext inheriting from ParseTree

Comment: antlr4::RuleContext *x = dynamic_cast<antlr4::RuleContext *>(tree);
auto ri = x->getRuleIndex();
auto name = parser.getRuleNames()[ri]; 
std::cout << name << std::endl;

This works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***kaby76 answer was correct***

```
antlr4::RuleContext *x = dynamic_cast<antlr4::RuleContext *>(node);
auto ri = x->getRuleIndex();
auto name = parser.getRuleNames()[ri];
std::cout << name << std::endl;
```

where node is some node in the ParseTree, name will be the parser rule's name as std::string

Also as Mike Lischke says below, it will be easier to use the rule index (ri) and an enum with the rules for comparison

Comment: Note: if you only want to check if a rule is a specific expected rule then it might be safer to use the rule enum value instead (e.g. `RULE_t`) as a string based comparison might not work anymore if a rule name is changed.